# probability of having a cycle in a bipartite graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Consider a bipartite graph with |L|=|R|=n.

Assume we have $c\cdot n$ random edges between vertices in L and vertices in R, where $c>1/2$.

I want to show that this graph would have a cycle with high probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered simulating it, and just counting the occurences?

Also, is your area of interest where $c \to 1/2$ or for special (low/high) $n$?

I also assume you have undirected graphs, and so make things easier.

I'd also consider first calculating the probability of having 4-cycles first. $(l_1,r_1,l_2,r_2,l_1)$
Then you can use calculations/estimates on pairs in L and pairs in R that would have both edges.

My first estimate would be that the 4-cycle I mentioned has all four edges with probability $c^4$, and the chance of missing this on all combinations of $l_1,r_2,l_3,r_4$ would be

$$ C = {n\choose 2}^2$$

$$ 1 - (1-c^4) ^ C $$

Which indeed is very small if you'd take let's say $n = 10$

With $n=10$ you have 2025 possible combinations, and although each combination only has 1/16 chance to be a cycle, this adds up to a very big chance.

Comment: There are $n^2$ possible edges, so shouldn't the probability that any given edge is included be roughly $cn/n^2=c/n$ rather than $c$? (Also, "with high probability" usually means that the probability should tend to $1$ as $n\to \infty$.)